# Stick div at the bottom of equally height cards

Tags: css, flexbox, bulma

I'm using [Bulma](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/) have a column of cards which need to have the same height regardless of the content.
To achieve so I have created the following class

```
.equal-height
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  height: 100%
```

My HTML looks like

```
<div class='columns is-multiline'>
  <div class='column is-one-fifth'>
    <div class='card equal-height'>
      <div class='card-content'>
        # CONTENT GOES HERE
      </div>
      <div class='card-footer'>
        # FOOTER GOES HERE
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='column is-one-fifth'>
    <div class='card equal-height'>
      <div class='card-content'>
        # CONTENT GOES HERE
      </div>
      <div class='card-footer'>
        # FOOTER GOES HERE
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which produces something like

[image]

Now I'm trying to make the `card-footer` to stick at the bottom of the card like below.

[image]

I have tried a few things with `flex` but they don't really make sense.
Any ideas on how I may do it?

Comment: then try with giving min-height to the blocks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add **"flex: auto;"** to **'.card-contents'** to make the card-footer to stick at the bottom of the card. Here is the working jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/AkshayaKT/1yc45dos/).

```
.equal-height {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.equal-height .card-content {
  flex: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, with Bulma loaded that doesn't seem to work. Nothing changes after updating the CSS.

Comment: Oh! In my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AkshayaKT/1yc45dos/) I have added Bulma and it seems to work, Could you please share a working link or something?

Comment: you are absolutely right. Somehow I was missing a closing div tag and because of that the style wasn't properly applied. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS

```
.card-footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

working demo : https://jsfiddle.net/baLg7940/